# Is there a statement to prepend an element T to a IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, linq

For example:

```
string element = 'a';
IEnumerable<string> list = new List<string>{ 'b', 'c', 'd' };

IEnumerable<string> singleList = ???; //singleList yields 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
```

Comment: In .NET Core it is built-in: ````public static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> Prepend<TSource> (this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource element);```` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.prepend?view=netcore-2.0)

Comment: And as part of implementing .Net Standard 2.0, it is included in .Net 4.7.1.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I take it you can't just `Insert` into the existing list?

Well, you could use `new[] {element}.Concat(list)`.

Otherwise, you could write your own extension method:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(
            this IEnumerable<T> values, T value) {
        yield return value;
        foreach (T item in values) {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
    ...

    var singleList = list.Prepend("a");
```

Comment: @Ian: I think you mean The One True Brace Style, from K&R onwards.

Comment: Shouldn't that be Concat() instead of Union()? Union() returns only distinct elements.

Comment: There was a typo: use Concat, not Union

Comment: @Ian - I use that style of braces on forums to preserve vertical space. For actual code, I honestly don't care what the brace style is.

Answer (score 8):

Since .NET framework 4.7.1 there is LINQ method for that:

```
list.Prepend("a");
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.prepend?view=netframework-4.7.1

Answer (score 6):

You can roll your own:

```
static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, T val) {
 yield return val;
 foreach (T t in seq) {
  yield return t;
 }
}
```

And then use it:

```
IEnumerable<string> singleList = list.Prepend(element);
```

Comment: I think it should be "yield return t" inside the foreach and the method should be static

Answer (score 5):

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(this IEnumerable<T> ie, T item)
    {
         return new T[] { item }.Concat(ie);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This would do it...

```
IEnumerable<string> singleList = new[] {element}.Concat(list);
```

If you wanted the singleList to be a List then...

```
IEnumerable<string> singleList = new List<string>() {element}.Concat(list);
```

... works too.

Comment: In your second example, singleList is an IEnumerable, not a List.

Comment: Fixed it for Martin.

Comment: But it was rejected. Shouldn't editors have higher standard here, like being able to comprehend code?

Comment: I think your edit was rejected because my second example *is* a List, but it's cast as an IEnumerable. The underlying data structure is a List, but exposed using the IEnumerable interface. The original question wanted to know how to prepend to an IEnumerable, so keeping the result as an IEnumerable makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Also:

```
IEnumerable<string> items = Enumerable.Repeat(item, 1).Concat(list);
```

Answer (score 2):

I find it convenient to be able to prepend multiple items in a chainable fashion. This version takes advantage of extension methods and `params`.

As a note, this version implicitly allows `null`, but it's just as easy to change it to `throw new NullReferenceException()` if that's the desired behavior.

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params T[] items)
    {
        return items.Concat(source ?? new T[0]);
    }
}
```

Allows for a very readable syntax for individual items:

```
GetItems().Prepend(first, second, third);
```

...and for collections of items:

```
GetItems().Prepend(GetMoreItems());
```

---

Finishing the example in the question results in:

```
string element = "a";
IEnumerable<string> list = new List<string>{ "b", "c", "d" };

IEnumerable<string> singleList = list.Prepend(element);
```

Comment: You seem to have a typo where you reference `source` but declare `sources`?

Comment: No problem, this is my favorite from of `Prepend` - unfortunately not what .Net Core and .Net Standard 2.0 added.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no such built-in statment, statement, but it's trivial to implement such function:

```
IEnumerable<T> PrependTo<T>(IEnumerable<T> underlyingEnumerable, params T[] values)
{
    foreach(T value in values)
        yield return value;

    foreach(T value in underlyingEnumerable)
        yield return value;
}

IEnumerable<string> singleList = PrependTo(list, element);
```

You can even make it an extension method if C# version allows for.

Comment: If you make this an extension method, You just implemented IEnumerable<T>.Union()   :P

Answer (score 1):

Just as a reminder - *List< T >* is not the only type of container. If you find yourself adding elements to the front of the list quite frequently, you can also consider using *Stack< T >* to implement your container. Once you have a stack

```
var container = new Stack<string>(new string[] { "b", "c", "d" });
```

you can always "prepend" an element via

```
container.Push("a");
```

and still use the collection as *IEnumerable< T >* like in

```
foreach (var s in container)
    // do sth with s
```

besides all the other methods typical for a stack like Pop(), Peek(), ...

Some of the solutions above iterate through the whole *IEnumeration< T >* just to prepend one element (or more than one in one case). This can be a very expensive operation if your collection contains a large number of elements and the frequency of prepending is relatively high.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at some of the examples, I think I'd prefer to reverse the extension to apply to the object.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> PrependTo<T>(this T value, IEnumerable<T> values) {
    return new[] { value }.Concat(values);
}
```

Used like

```
var singleList = element.PrependTo(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Niklas & NetMage in the comments.

There is a new built-in Prepend methond in C#.

[image]