# Prepending an entry to an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq

I have a complicated IEnumerable that iterates through line-segments so that the end point of the previous segment is the same as the start point of the next segment. I want to extract an array of the points in order, without duplications. So it has to pick up the start point of the first segment, then each midpoint once, and finally the end point of the last segment.

What I have come up with is

```
Class Segment 
{
   public Vector Start { get; set; }
   public Vector End { get; set; }
   ...
}

Class Path
{
   ...
   public void Trace(IEnumerable<Segment> Route)
   {
      Vector[] Points = new List<Vector>() { Route.First().Start }.Concat(from segment in Route select segment.End).ToArray();
      ...
   }
}
```

Where (if Route were indexable) `Route[i].End = Route[i+1].Start` for all `i` except the last.

While this works (I think - I'm not at a point to test it yet), it seems rather clunky to me. I hate having to create a list of a single entry just to start off the process. Is there a more efficient or elegant solution?

(Edit: originally I had "Union" instead of "Concat".)

Comment: Are you aware that you are attempting to assign an array to a Vector variable? `Vector Points = new List<Vector>(...).ToArray()`

Comment: `Enumerable.Repeat(Route.First().Start, 1).Union(...)`? Is your entire problem with the list instantiation?

Comment: @JacobHuckins - I noticed the omission shortly after posting and quickly corrected it, but not quite quick enough, it seems!

Comment: Why just don't use built-in [`Prepend`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.prepend?view=netcore-3.1) method? It's available from .NET FW 4.7.1

Comment: There is also an existing question [Is there a statement to prepend an element T to a IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802537/is-there-a-statement-to-prepend-an-element-t-to-a-ienumerablet)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - for some reason the Prepend method is not available to me. I may have it limited to v4.5 (I'm picking this back up after a delay of some months, and don't recall all the choices I made originally.) Thank you for the link. I did search, but for some reason that one did not come up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a simple extension method.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(this T source, T item)
{
    yield return item;
    foreach (T t in source) yield return t;
}
```

To use it:

```
public void Trace(IEnumerable<Segment> Route)
{
    var item = from segment in Route select segment.End;
    
    Vector[] points = Route.Prepend(item).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: But what is a prepend, if not a Concat or Union? Also, `T item` should be `IEnumerable<T> items`.

Comment: @CodeCaster - I believe `T item` is correct. But thank you for mentioning Concat, as that is the operation I should have instead of Union.

Comment: @Paul yeah I meant `this IEnumerable<T> source`.